# MaaS not detecting IPMI. Sometimes

Tags: maas, ipmi

trusty LTS, MaaS 1.7.3+bzr3363, Dell c6105s.  I boot new nodes, they are found, but no IPMI is detected.  Nodes fail in commissioning, even if set to WOL and powered up by hand.  I delete an old node from from MaaS, rebooted it, and IPMI info is found.  I grepped maas.log for IPMI and found no entries in the last 10 days.  I grepped pserv.log, and maas-django.log and found no instances of ipmi of IPMI.

How do I debug the ipmi enlistment process?

What logs could I review/include to help determine the cause?

Comment: Can you provide the version of MAAS you are using? Have you tried setting the IPMI credentials manually? Which commissioning scripts are failing?

Comment: MaaS 1.7.3+bzr3363.  The problem was that system did not have an apt cache, and didn't have internet access.  Under those conditions it can't detect IPMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that, as I was set up, my MaaS server did not have an APT cache.  Because there was not a cache, it did not have the libraries needed to recognize IPMI.  Once I connected the MaaS server to the net, it had access to the libs and worked correctly.

My next move is to create a apt cache on the server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: rmustakos: Is this intended as an answer to your question? It seems to me that it *is*, but I am not sure. If it is, can you expand it to clarify, and to explain how it applies to your specific situation? There are no other answers or comments here and clearly you are not attempting to critique or request clarification *from yourself*; nonetheless, it's hard for me to tell if this is really an answer. (*If* this is an attempt to provide more information in your question, and not an attempt to answer it, then you should edit the question instead.) @NewUSer

Comment: This is incorrect. MAAS does not require internet access to determine power control method. MAAS does require access to an Ubuntu archive to install the ipmi tools to manage the ipmi on the machine using inband management. As long as the user either has a proxy or an apt-mirror running and setup in MAAS, they do not require an internet connection. Your answer is to vague and doesn't even answer the question. The question didn't even state that no internet was available.

Comment: @Blake Rouse.
Yes, my question did not state that, because I did not know that it was relevant until I determined it was part of the root cause.I also didn't mention how many nics the machine had or a million other things that could be relevant.  My apologies.  
"MAAS does not require internet access" and 
"MAAS does require access to an Ubuntu archive"
Yes, it didn't require it until it required it, as you stated.